# Creating calculated fields in sql

Tags: sql-server, average, alter

This will seem rudimentary but I can't find a concise example online that matches up.

I have three fields; `m1`, `m2`, and `m3`. I need to create a column or field that is the average of them three. The calculated field would be titled employment. Would the following code be suffice?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename ADD Employment AS Select ((m1+m2+m3)/3)
```

Sample data

```
m1   20    20    30
m2   15    17    25
m3   60    77    13
```

desired result.

```
Name        m1    m2    m3   Employment
Auto body    20    20    30     23
Auto Parts   15    17    25     19
Auto Sales   60    77    13     50
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are very close, it's called `Computed Column`

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename ADD Employment AS ((m1+m2+m3)/3)
```

**Update:**

If you would like to force data type for a computed column, you could do the following

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename ADD Employment AS CAST((m1+m2+m3)/3 AS Numeric (9,0))
```

Comment: Ok, to add on. I forgot that my computed field/column needs to be numeric (9). Would I add it in as such


     ALTER TABLE dbo.tablename ADD Employment Numeric (9) AS ((m1+m2+m3)/3)

Answer (score 7):

You can check [Computed Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table)

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
    col1 int,
    col2 int,
    col3 int,
    col4 as (col1*col2*col3)/3

)

insert into t1  values(1,2,3)

select * from t1
```